# SAS Call Execute passing numbers as arguments

Tags: dynamic, sas

I want to perform a function call passing date as parameter row in dataset:

`data _Null_;
        set calc_dates;
        CALL EXECUTE ('%doStuff('||date||');');
    run;`

However this does not work as the 'date' is passed as string. Even if I try to convert it to number any numeric evaluations explode. The following work around works, but feels overly complicated:
`

```
%macro loopMeUp; 
proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :MaxActions from calc_dates;
quit;

%do i=1 %to &MaxActions;
    data _NULL_;
        set calc_dates;
        if _N_=&i_sjm.;
        call symput("temppi",date);
    run;
    %DoStuff(&temppi.);
%end;
%mend loopMeUp;
```

`
Anyone know how to pass numbers (dates) as parameters thought call execute procedure or other 'easy way'?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.  What format is the 'date' column?  As you see below, the unformatted date value is passed to the macro using your technique, as it would appear you are expecting:

```
  %macro dostuff(param);
    %put &param;
  %mend;
  data _null_;
    format date date9.;
    date='31DEC1999'd;
    put date=;
    call execute('%dostuff('!!date!!');');
  run;
```

gives:

```
date=31DEC1999 
14609
```

If the date column is actually a character field, then you will need to convert it to a date (numeric) type in order to perform calculations.  Passing these values via `call symput` is identical either way.